# deleting item from array using mongoose in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am making a to-do list app. I want to delete one item from an array, but using Model.findOneAndUpdate() it is not working. Please help me if I am making a mistake in syntax, or you can suggest another way.

```
app.post("/delete", function(req,res){
  
  const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox.trim();
  const listName = req.body.nameOfItemToDelete;

  if (listName==="Today"){
    Item.findOneAndDelete(checkedItemId)
      .then(function (item) {
        res.redirect("/")
        console.log("item is deleted")
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        res.redirect("/")
        console.log("err while deleting")
      })
  }
  else{
    
    List.findOneAndUpdate({ name: listName }, { $pull: { items: { _id:  checkedItemId  } } })
      .then(function(foundlist){
        res.redirect("/"+listName)
      })
  }
  
})
```

Please review the code and if possible then help me

Comment: Shubham please the share the MongoDB data structure so we can see and then give you the answer

Comment: And also share more details about how you handling the delete I mean to say what procedure you are following to delete the item. As soon you update the code ping me in comment

Comment: const listSchema ={
  name:String,
  items:[]
}

const List = mongoose.model("List",listSchema);

Comment: No the screen shot of data when you saved or created it in MongoDB from atlas or compass whatever you are using to see the data

Comment: link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QuDz5A84Xb-rCogAHLE7kRvDg9fM8G3m/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
List.findOneAndUpdate({ name: listName }, { item: { _id:  checkedItemId  } })
  .then(function(foundlist){
    res.redirect("/"+listName)
  })
```

Based on your comments, you need to ensure that your List schema has a reference to your Item schema sub-documents as suggested in the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) like so:

```
const listSchema = new Schema({
   name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   items: [{
      type: mongoose.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Item'
   }]
});
```

This way each item is a sub-document and the `List` contains an array of all the relevant `ObjectId` related to that list. This is the best way to handle references between two documents. Otherwise your `items` is just an array of strings and you will need to use traditional search techniques to pull items from an array (select by index, using loops or `array.find()` etc) which are not as optimised as sub-documents.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Can you post your List schema or a sample List document?

Comment: const listSchema ={
  name:String,
  items:[]
}

const List = mongoose.model("List",listSchema);

Comment: I see, you have items as just a standard array. You need to use sub-documents. I have updated answer.

Comment: I have noticed from your database screenshot that your array is called `item` and not `items` and that it has two properties ( `name`, `_id`). I have updated the `List.findOneAndUpdate` answer to match. Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: Thank you @jQueery for this help. I spent last few days to resolve this error.